# Unable to locate conda environment after creating it using .yml file

Tags: r, bash, conda

I'm trying to create (and activate & use) a Conda environment using a .yml file (in fact, I'm following instructions on this GitHub page: https://github.com/RajLabMSSM/echolocatoR). I'm working in a cluster computing system running Linux.

```bash
conda env create -f https://github.com/RajLabMSSM/echolocatoR/raw/master/inst/conda/echoR.yml
```

After running the above line of code, I'm trying to activate the environment:

```
conda activate echoR
```

However, this returns the following message:

> Could not find conda environment: echoR
> You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.

When checking the list of environments in *.conda/environments.txt*, the echoR environment is indeed not listed.

I'm hoping for some suggestions of what might be the issue here.

Comment: Can not reproduce.

Comment: What was the output after running the `conda env create` command?

Comment: You mention this is on HPC - is this running in an interactive session? or is this executing as a script?

Comment: @merv the output after the ```conda env create``` command was as follows:
```Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done```

```Solving environment: / ```
 
Ends abruptly after some time without additional output.

I was running this in an interactive session.

Comment: Sounds like the process might be getting killed. The Python solver can sometimes use a lot of memory on large environments (which this is) - try increasing the amount you request from SLURM/SGE. Or use Mamba instead (a compiled version of Conda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Likely Cause: Out of Memory

Given the HPC context, the solver is likely trying to exceed the allocated memory and getting killed. The Python-based Conda solver is not very resource efficient and can struggle with large environments. This particular environment is quite large, given it mixes both Python and R, and it doesn't give exact specifications for R and Python versions - only lower bounds - which makes the SAT search space enormous.

### Profiling Memory ( [image: so-echoR] )

I attempted to use a GitHub Workflow to profile the memory usage. Using Mamba, it solved without issue; using Conda, the job was killed because the GitHub runner ran out of memory (7GB max). The breakdown was:

| Tool | Memory (MB) | User Time (s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mamba | 745 | 195.45 |
| Conda | > 6,434 | > 453.34 |

### Workarounds

#### Use Mamba

As a drop-in replacement for Conda that is *compiled*, Mamba is much more resource efficient. Also, it has seen welcome adoption in the bioinformatics community (e.g., it is default frontend for Snakemake).

As the GitHub workflow demonstrates, the Mamba-based creation works perfectly fine with the YAML as is.

#### Request more memory

Ask SLURM/SGE for more memory for your interactive session. Conda seems to need more that 6.5 GB (maybe try 16GB?).

#### Create a better YAML

The first thing one could do to get a faster solve is provide exact versions for the Python and R. The Mamba solution resolved to `python=3.9` `r-base=4.0`.

There's also a bunch of development-level stuff in the environment that is completely unnecessary for end-users. But that's more something to bother the developers about.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive reply @merv! I'll give mamba a try first